# Why i get Error When i try to record audio? "Sounddevice.PortAudioError"

Tags: python, audio

```
from scipy.io.wavfile import write<br>
import sounddevice as sd


fs = 44100
seconds = 5

myrecording = sd.rec(int(seconds * fs), samplerate=fs, channels=2)<br>
sd.wait()

write('micro.wav', fs, myrecording)
```

[The Error That I Get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQi02.png)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Have you tried this: https://github.com/spatialaudio/python-sounddevice/issues/89? Also, please don't post your outputs as an image.

Comment: i checked it now but i'm using windows, the problem is in the PortAudio lib ?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://github.com/spatialaudio/python-sounddevice/issues/74#issuecomment-480397175) and [this](https://github.com/spatialaudio/python-sounddevice/issues/89#issuecomment-511007909)

Comment: i'm using windows i can't use those command

Comment: As I know, `conda`(or equivalent) can be installed on Windows, if you can't use it, you can do what these commands actually do.

Comment: and if i install (conda) and every thing will be ok ..... when i'll try my script in another pc, will it work ??

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot know the answer to such questions :) If you check this, then you will find out

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors.